# How to put uniqe id in Redux for every object in array?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an object`dailyData: {}`, and when I'm making ajax request, this object contains some data like this: 
[image]

So, how to put uniqe id (for example using library `shortid`) to every object in `dailyData.daily` ?

Just in case, my reducer's code:

```
        case GET_DAILY_DATA: {
            return {
                ...state,
                dailyData: action.data,

            }
        }
```

Comment: You don't need Redux anymore: https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactn

Comment: "I have an array" -- looks to me like you have an object there.

Comment: @jmargolisvt sorry, you're right!

Comment: @LucaFagioli Redux isn't actual now?

Comment: @БогданЧубко it is still _unreasonably_ actual, since you can achieve the same things using a terribly simpler approach, used by [reactn](https://npmjs.com/package/reactn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to iterate through the whole array and add the unique id to each of the objects in daily.

So, before saving the data to your state you can do something like this:

```
dailyData.daily.map(data => {...data, uniqueId: id }))
```

Don't use the index as unique id, just in case you have to append more data to this in the future, it won't remain unique anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index of each object, I don't know the exact pourpose of doing that but if you going to iterate the array you have access to the index, like that:

```
this.props.daily.map((item, index) => }
    //use the index like an unique ID
})
```

You need to be careful of how to use it. This way works pretty well in some cases and don't in others.